# fprintf is printing two values instead of one

Tags: c, file, hex, printf

I'm using `fprintf` in order to print a value to a file. Here is a simplified code snippet. Here, I want the file to contain the single value 0x0A.

```
int main() {
    FILE *fp;
    unsigned int hex[] = { 10 }; // Value to be written (10 = 0x0A)

    fp = fopen("file.txt", "w"); // Open
    fprintf(fp, "%s", hex); // Write
    fclose(fp); // Close

    return 0;
}
```

The file looks like this (viewed in a hex editor):
[image]

It contains the values 0x0D and 0x0A but I expected just 0x0A.
Setting the value in `hex` to 0x0A instead of 10 yields the same result.

For reference, these are the results of setting the value in `hex` to 11 and 12 respectively:
[image]
[image]

which are correct.

What's actually going on here? Where is this 0x0D coming from?

Comment: Ah... I didn't notice that 10 was ascii for a line feed. That might well be it.

Comment: Have you tried %c rather than %s ?

Comment: Yes, %c gives the wrong output as well.

Comment: What you said, user3121023, was the problem. If you write it as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Why not like this `fwrite(hex, sizeof(*hex), 1, fp)`?

Comment: Didn't the compiler issue a warning?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, you didn't specify which operating system/compiler are you using, but I guess it is Windows (or not unix/linux) because it is converting on `printf(3)` output a sequence of `\n` char (`0x0a`) into a **CRLF** seq `\r\n` (`0x0d 0x0a`)  If that's the case and you don't want the translation to be done, just add modifier `b` to the open mode to show as `"wb"` so the translation is not done.

```
fp = fopen("file.txt", "wb"); // Open (for writing in binary mode)
```

if you move the program to a unix machine, there's no problem as those modifiers are included in POSIX.

## note

you have a mistake in your code, as you pass an array of unsigned integers to printf with a `%s` modifier, and that's not correct.  `%s` format sequence allows you to pass only a pointer to char pointing to a null terminated string (your pointer was by luck, but you run into Undefined Behaviour with your code)  Valid should be:

```
char hex[] = { 10, 0 }; // decimal char literals.
```

or

```
char hex[] = "\012"; // octal char.  No provision for decimal char literals.
```

or

```
char hex[] = "\x0a"; // hex char literal.
```